# Can I develop in SQL Server Express for later deployment in a full SQL Server?

Tags: sql, sql-server, vb.net, sql-server-2012-express

Very new to SQL Server. I am needing to develop a SQL Server database to run with an iPhone app I am developing. It will ultimately be running with our full-fledged SQL Server database, which is administered by our IT guy, but I'd like to have a local database for testing.

Two questions:

1. I assume I can use SQL Server Express 2012 for this purpose, since it is advertised as such; but would it be better/easier to use what appears to be the simplest form, LocalDB, in conjunction with VB2010? It will be running on my office PC to which a port is open for TCP communication from my app (which is working fine). Would LocalDB work for that, if the communication occurs in the VB app? Or will I need to get the SQL Server Express edition?
2. If a prototype database is developed in SQL Server Express, can it migrate to our full-fledged SQL Server when the app is taken "live"? (I am not sure right now what version our full-fledged SQL Server is, but I was planning on using SQL Server Express 2012.)

Comment: Yes, you can attach the MDB file to your production environment.  Your IT guy should know how to do that. Why don't you ask him? :)

Comment: Don't spread this around, but our IT guy is kinda hard to work with. That's why I want to create my own database. The less interaction with him, the less painful it will be for me.

Comment: @Menefee: `.mdb` is MS Access - Bill is talking about SQL Server - that would be a  `.mdf` file then (plus a `.ldf` transaction log file)

Comment: @marc_s Thanks. I seldom deal with the file itself directly.

Comment: Well, you'll get a chuckle out of this. I asked our IT guy, and he says that for this application he will probably be using Access. He said it was my choice if I wanted to use SQL or Access, as long as there's a way to export/import. He seemed to think there was. But still, I got a good education from you folks about SQL. Thanks for everything!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Yes, the Express editions **ARE** the full-fledged SQL Server version - no code difference, only some marketing-driven restrictions (on database size and so forth).

You can absolutely develop your system on a SQL Server Express, and then just detach your database from Express and re-attach it to a Standard or Enterprise edition server. No fuss, no migration, no conversion - nothing - it just works. Period.

And I would probably even argue having a **server** installation (of your Express) edition is the better choice than LocalDB. That way, you're *already* using the server-based approach as you will later on in production, and you won't fall into any "convenience" traps offered by LocalDB (or other approaches) that make dev life easier - but rollout to production can be a challenge. When you use SQL Server Express as a server-based installation from the get to - you have the "real deal" from day one.

Comment: Just make sure that your local SQL Server Express version is >= the server deployment version. This was very confusing with 2008 & 2008 R2, which a lot of people thought were the same. With 2012 this is potentially still an issue unless you ensure that the deployment server is also running SQL Server 2012.

Comment: @AaronBertrand: spot on - good advice! Lots of folks still believe just setting the compatibility level makes their backups "compatible" with earlier versions ...

Comment: @Giorgi: no - SQL Server Express is an excellent learning tool - it's the full SQL Server, but free to use and play around with. Go for it!